# passing variables via pysimplegui to pyperclip

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

I want to start by thanking everyone for taking the time to read this and help me out. IM rand new to pysimplegui and am having a hard time passing this variable into pyperclip. I'm positive my syntax is wrong. The actual line for pyperclip is correct, just not for pysimplegui, any help is appreciated.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pyperclip

sg.theme('BluePurple')

layout = [[sg.Text('Enter the Domain and TLD:')],
          [sg.Input(key='domain')],
          [sg.Input(key='tld')],
          [sg.Button('Convert to Regex'), sg.Button('Exit')]]

window = sg.Window('HTTP Regex Maker', layout)

while True:  # Event Loop
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    if event == 'Convert to Regex':
        # Update the "output" text element to be the value of "input" element
        pyperclip.copy("^([A-Za-z0-9.-]*\.)?"+domain+"\."+tld)
window.close()
```

Comment: You can get the value of element from dictionary `values` by key of element or event. For text of `sg.Input(key='domain')`, it is `values['domain']`.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote it slightly and is working now. hoe this helps someone.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pyperclip

sg.theme('SandyBeach')      

layout = [ 
    [sg.Text('Please enter Domain and TLD')], 
    [sg.Text('domain', size =(15, 1)), sg.InputText()], 
    [sg.Text('tld', size =(15, 1)), sg.InputText()], 
    [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()] 
] 

window = sg.Window('HTTP Regex Maker', layout) 
event, values = window.read() 
window.close() 

pyperclip.copy("^([A-Za-z0-9.-]*\.)?"+values[0]+"\."+values[1])
```